# Powermock replace superclass method

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock

I have the following code:

```
public class ClassA {

 public Object buid(){
   Object obj=new Object();
   //building object...
   return obj;
 }

public class ClassB extends ClassA {

 public Object build(){
   Object obj=super.build();
   //some operations with obj
   return obj;
 }

}
```

I want to test ClassB#build. In order to do that I need to mock super.build() invocation. Is it possible with powermock?

Supress is working fine, but i didn't manage to replace this method with MemberModifier.replace.

Comment: It looks like it's not possible without a manual build: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=51

Comment: Yeah, seems so. Thanks for the link.